# How is client cookie value generated in Rails 4?

Tags: linux, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies, session-cookies

How is client cookie value generated in Rails 4?
I want to get autologin cookie value to make it possible open site without entering login/password.
It is used for internal Rails administration app (Rails 3).

This is an example of realization in Rails 3:
https://gist.github.com/sadfuzzy/a39be54ecd333d569b11#file-session_generator-rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally, I've got the answer:
Rails 4 is very alike with Rails 3 in generating cookie value:
https://gist.github.com/sadfuzzy/9026b9ab8fc4a766e184